# android popupmenu truncated at the right edge of the screen

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a button placed at the right edge of the screen.

This button expands a popup menu.

The problem is that, due to the location of the button, the menu appears truncated.

The screenshot below shows the activity, which is forced to horizontal orientation. The button "Select image" expands the popup menu, which appears truncated.

How can I make it completely visible?

thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Maybe a little bit of your code could help to see the issue.

Comment: I think that the only relevant method to this issue that I used is show(), within PopupMenu Class.